# How can I load a table in PHP and have the background color of some rows highlighted?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am not looking for alternating rows... Rather, I have two tables A and B and Field1 is present in both. I want to present TableA and everywhere that the field1 matches the field1 in TableB, I would like to highlight the row. How can I do this?

I know how to do this in SQL, but the question is how to present this in the browser. I think I must use javascript. Any advice?

### Here is the PHP Script that generates Table A. I would like to change the background of rows in this output where the aif_id is also present in Table B

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("SELECT aif_id, fee_source_id, company_name_per_sedar, document_filing_date FROM a_aif ORDER BY aif_id DESC");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<table id=\"all_aifs\">";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><b>Document ID</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>Filing Date</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>PDF</b></th>";
echo "</tr>";

foreach($result as $index => $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$row[fee_source_id]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[company_name_per_sedar]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[document_filing_date]</td>";
echo "<td>Placeholder</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
$dbh = NULL;
?>
```

### PHP Script for TableB

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$result = $dbh->query("SELECT aif_id, fee_source_id, company_name_per_sedar, document_filing_date FROM a_aif_remaining LIMIT 0,50");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><b>Document ID</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>Filing Date</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>PDF</b></th>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($result as $index => $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[fee_source_id]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[company_name_per_sedar]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[document_filing_date]</td>";
    echo "<td>Placeholder</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<br>";
$dbh = NULL;
?>
```

### UPDATED CODE

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("SELECT aif_id, fee_source_id, company_name_per_sedar, document_filing_date FROM a_aif_remaining");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$match = $dbh->query("SELECT a_aif.aif_id FROM a_aif INNER JOIN a_aif_remaining WHERE a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id");?>

<?php if ( !empty($result) ) : ?>

<table id="all_aifs">
<tr>
<th><b>Document ID</b></th>
<th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>
<th><b>Filing Date</b></th>
<th><b>PDF</b></th>
</tr>

<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
<tr>
<?= $row['aif_id'] == true ? ' class="match"' : '' ?>
<td><?php echo $row[fee_source_id]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row[company_name_per_sedar]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row[document_filing_date]; ?></td>
<td>Placeholder</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
<br>

<?php endif;
$dbh = NULL;
?>
```

Comment: How are you currently displaying the information?

Comment: could you draw what you need in paint or any other drawing application and post the image with your question to demonstrate the issue clearly.

Comment: This is easy enough to do... but we will need to see your output script to help you.

Comment: @ArtaexMedia I have the data stored as HTML Tables that are called via javascript function to the browser.

Comment: @sємsєм that is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @ROYFinley I have included the PHP scripts that generate the HTML tables...

Comment: Veger's answer will do exactly what you need.

Comment: @ArtaexMedia I asked this before editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are going to keep your code maintainable and clean as well, then you should avoid printing HTML TAGS.

The way not to go:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><b>Document ID</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>Filing Date</b></th>";
echo "<th><b>PDF</b></th>";
```

The way to go:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("SELECT aif_id, fee_source_id, company_name_per_sedar, document_filing_date FROM a_aif_remaining LIMIT 0,50");
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>

<?php if ( !empty($result) ) : ?>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th><b>Document ID</b></th>
  <th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>
  <th><b>Filing Date</b></th>
  <th><b>PDF</b></th>
 </tr>

<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row[fee_source_id]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[company_name_per_sedar]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[document_filing_date]; ?></td>
    <td>Placeholder</td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</table>

<br />


<?php endif; ?>
```

Conclusion:

1) The code now looks more readable and clean as well
2) You separated PHP from HTML
3) You can easily determine a problem once it occurs (like, `parse error at ..`, `unexcepted ';' ...`

**Back to your question**

So how can you highlight a row you need? Well it's easy, just use if/else in a `foreach` loop, like

```
<?php foreach($result as $k => $v): ?>


 <?php if ( $k == 'some_value_you_expect_to_be_highlighted' ) : ?>

    <tr>... should be highlighted  ...</tr>
 <?php else : ?>
    <tr>.... a regular row</tr>

 <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Really helpful when people point things out like that... :D Makes more sense to me now.

Comment: I have a few questions... what is the <?php endig; ?> for? is that to close the if argument? And also should I have a close db on the bottom of this too?

Comment: @BenJones The established link to `$db` would be closed automatically. You shouldn't close it manually. The alternate control structures like, `endif`, `endwhile`, `endfor` , `if (..) :` used to simplify work with HTML. You can find good examples of it in `Drupal`, `Joomla`, `Symfony` etc. Also, check `http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php`

Answer (score 3):

Perform your check in SQL (since you know how to do so).

In PHP use the result of your check to add an (additional) class-attribute to the HTML element that needs the highlight (just like 'alternating rows' do):

```
<?php
$query = ... // perform your SQL query
// TODO Open HTML table
// TODO Loop though results:
  $row = ... // fetch you row here
?>
<tr <?= $row['my_check'] == true ? ' class="match"' : '' ?>>
  <td><?= $row['field'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
// TODO close HTML table
```

This (incomplete) example uses the SQL check (named `my_check`) and adds the `match` class when required. In CSS you can use this `match` class to apply highlighting:

```
.match {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I have implemented what you have suggested but I am not getting the desired result. I have updated my code for you to see.

Comment: You do not have the `class='match'` part **inside** the `<tr>`-element... :)

Comment: ahhh that's why there was two angle brackets on the right side. Thanks! So this will make all the rows red where I have fixed up my css eh? very cool! Keep ya posted!

Comment: Yes, it should work. And, you might want to use a more descriptive class name (instead of `match`) ;)

Comment: Hi Veger, I have done this but it made all the rows red... see here: http://theauditorsreport.com/_sandbox/ and click "All AIFs". I included the 'my_match' as the aif_id, which of course it a match... duh. So I should be including the variable `$match` in those square parenthesis?

Comment: I am no SQL expect, but I do not see your field comparison in SQL: I would suspect to see something like `SELECT tableA.field1 = tableB.field1 AS my_check FROM tableA, tableB`. But again I am no SQL expert...

Comment: I made the above change (switched the term from my_match to $match but now I am only getting those rows that are a match and unfortunately with no CSS

Comment: You need to combine these SQL queries somehow, as you need to use the original query to grab all data and the additional test to use the highlighting. But, I guess you'd need to ask a new question and hope a SQL expert will help you out!

Comment: @Vever my SQL is this `SELECT a_aif.aif_id FROM a_aif INNER JOIN a_aif_remaining WHERE a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id`. I don't think you can select x = y from in mysql but I have no idea... I tested my query in php myadmin and it worked and the result was just the rows that had field1 in common.

Answer (score 2):

You should simply add a class to the rows where the data matches, and set a background color in the associated CSS.

```
<table> <tr class="matching"> ... </tr>
```

How to write the appropriate CSS is beyond the scope of this answer. ;-)

Whether that class is added by your web server's PHP code, or by some JavaScript in the client, depends on the design of your Web application.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't 'have' to use JavaScript. You can use PHP.

When generating your rows, check whether the condition is met and put your 'highlighted' class into the row definition.

Pseudocode:

```
<?php
    if(Condition) echo "<tr class='highlighted'>";
    else echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>CellStuff</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I could understand your problem correct but I dont think you need JS.
You can calculate if a cell/row should be highlighted in PHP and set a css class, also in PHP.